# CSS how can I change some character's font color automatically?

Tags: css, fonts, colors

Say I have a `div` that shows some text like this:

```
<div id="some_text">abc_123+xyz</div>
```

I would like to set a single character's color in RED, if it's neither numeric nor alphabetic.

This is the regular expression I used to identify numeric and alphabetic characters: `[0-9A-Za-z]`, but I got stuck now...

How can I do this, is this possible?

Comment: Not possible using only CSS, as far as I know.

Comment: I think you have to us JS or wrap the chars in spans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible using only CSS, because the characters are not in a separate element that can be styled.

You'll have to add some JavaScript to create the required elements, for example:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('some_text');

div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(
    /([^a-z0-9])/gi,
    '<span style="color: red">$1</span>'
);
```

```html
<div id="some_text">abc_123+xyz</div>
```

Comment: It's pretty quick to solve it via javascript, thank you~